# Function to provide a default value when working with std::map

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a function, which will give me a default value when the key is not inside a std::map. In all cases will my default value be numerical_limit::infinity().
Hovewer this simple example is not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <limits>

template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
ValueType mapDefaultInf(const std::map<KeyType, ValueType> & map, const KeyType & key)
{
    if(!map.contains(key))
    {
        return std::numeric_limits<ValueType>::infinity();
    }
    else
    {
        return map[key];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> map;
    auto el = mapDefaultInf(map, "alexey");
    std::cout << el << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error is:

```
main.cpp:29:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘mapDefaultInf(std::map, int>&, const char [7])’
```

Can someone help me understand the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits::infinity()` is not meaningful for non-floating point types (more specifically those that do not have `std::numeric_limits:has_inifinity == true`). I think you might intend it to be `std::numeric_limits::max()` for such types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you use `operator[]` on the map object inside the function.  That will never be allowed because it is a non-const function and you have passed the map by const reference.  Instead you should rewrite the function implementation to use iterators:

```
template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
ValueType mapDefaultInf(const std::map<KeyType, ValueType> & map, const KeyType & key)
{
    const auto it = map.find(key);
    return it != map.end() ?  it->second : std::numeric_limits<ValueType>::infinity();
}
```

Second of all you have an ambiguity in the key type.  You need to pass in a std::string.  Like this:

```
auto el = mapDefaultInf(map, std::string("alexey"));
```

Comment: This answer works so I upvoted it, but Quimby's allows the user to not have to manually translate everything to a string.

Comment: Oh I agree with Quimby in that regard.  I was just trying to keep it simple (and I didn't want to steal his answer!)

Comment: @Joe Nice catch about `[]`, feel free to "steal" from me in the future ;)

Answer (score 5):

You have constrained your template too much, as it is written it requires the keys in the map to be the of the same type as `key` parameter.

That fails because your map stores `std::string` but you pass a string literal which technically has a type of `const char[7]`.

Just make the header:

```
template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType,typename T>
ValueType mapDefaultInf(const std::map<KeyType, ValueType> & map, const T& key)
```

It will allow implicit conversions to take place at `map.contains(key)` call and will just fail with more complicated error message if you pass it an incompatible type. It's not like the current error is a pinnacle of readability anyway.

Comment: I tried a more complicated `ValueType mapDefaultInf(const std::map<KeyType, ValueType> & map, const typename std::map<KeyType, ValueType>::key_type & key)` signature, which removed the requirement for `typename T`, but is harder to read. I like yours better. Be sure to note in your answer that `std::map::operator[]` will fail on `const std::map` types, so they need to use `std::map::at`.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I'll admit, I did not try to run the code, thanks about `[]`. Yea, nice idea, it enables implicit casts and makes the type inside the function fixed.